# How to change the background image in a PhoneGap app?

Tags: jquery, css, html, cordova

I'm trying to change the body background image whenever orientation changes. This seemed pretty easy at first, so I tried this code:

```
    function onBodyLoad() {     
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        document.addEventListener("orientationchange", onOrientationChange, true);
    }

    function onOrientationChange(e) {
        var orientation = (window.orientation == -90 || window.orientation == 90) ? "landscape" : "portrait";
        console.log("orientation: " + orientation);
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(images/" + orientation + ".png) no-repeat fixed center top");
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("at onDeviceReady");
        onOrientationChange();
    }
```

Every time I change the orientation, I get the correct orientation displayed in the console - meaning my event gets trigrerred properly. But the background does not change, or even initially set (even though I call the handler manually in onDeviceReady - and I see the console output that it was called). Something in the `$("body")` line just doesn't work. I tried several combinations of CSS properties and even `.css({"backgroundImage" : "..."})`, but to no avail.

For the record, there's a landscape.png and portrait.png in an images folder, in the same directory as the html page.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery("body") ... instead?

Comment: @tnt runs as a PhoneGap app in an iPad emulator - so I guess mobile Safari

Comment: maybe more appropriate to use if(Height > Width) to calculate orientation for now! just add an console log to see if the orientation is working correctly.

Comment: @tnt Why? The event shoots properly and returns correct results

Comment: @TTG just checking possibilities. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Maybe without jQuery?**

```
function onOrientationChange(e) {
    var orientation = (window.orientation == -90 || window.orientation == 90) ? "landscape" : "portrait";
    console.log("orientation: " + orientation);
    document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('images/" + orientation + ".png')";
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat="no-repeat";
    document.body.style.backgroundAttachment="fixed";
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition="top center";
}
```

As @scessor said you can only set the `url` of the `background-image` property, so you should use `background` or the other `backgroundXXX` properties instead.

**Using classes**

```
function onOrientationChange(e){
    var orientation = (window.orientation == -90 || window.orientation == 90) ? "landscape" : "portrait";
    console.log("orientation: " + orientation);
    $("body").removeClass("portrait").removeClass("landscape").addClass(orientation);
}
```

Comment: Ok, with a minor fix of a typo (you need a " after image/ and one more before .png) this actually works. But why doesn't the jQuery expression work, even after changing the property to 'background'?

Comment: Can you try if jQuery even works? Try this: $("body").hide() when orientation changes. If all the body element hides then jQuery works so there's still a syntax error in your code above.

Comment: Yes, $("body").hide() works. jQuery is properly included and functioning - other than being able to change the background image. Maybe I've stumbled upon a PhoneGap/jQuery issue?

Comment: You can also manipulate with classes and set background image in CSS. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

`background-image` only defines an url (see [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-image)):

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url(\"images/" + orientation + ".png\")");
```

or use `background` with an url and more background parameters (see [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background)):

```
$("body").css("background", "url(\"images/" + orientation + ".png\") no-repeat fixed center top transparent");
```

=== UPDATE ===

Try following:

```
$("body").css({ 
    backgroundImage: "url('images/" + orientation + ".png')"
    ,backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
    ,backgroundAttachment: "fixed"
    ,backgroundPosition: "top center"
});
```

or

```
 $("body").css({ 
    background: "url('images/" + orientation + ".png') no-repeat fixed top center transparent"
});
```

Comment: I tried the "background" property, instead of the "background-image" one - still, no results.

Comment: Is the javascript in a script-tag in the html or do you include an additional js-file? If you have an additional file, is this in the same directory as the html file?

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that pitfall. It's in the html file - as stated in the question

Comment: I've added quotes around the file, maybe not all browsers accept the url-parameter without them. Can you test my current answer again?

Comment: Tried with/out, double/single quotes. jQuery expression doesn't work. Changing the exact document properties as suggested below does. Still, I want to use jQuery.

Comment: copied/pasted your lines - nope :(

Comment: 1.) I've added the `transparent` parameter, maybe it needs all parameters. 2.) In a comment you said `image/` not `images/`, which one is correct?

Comment: I've added alternatives in my answer.

Comment: images/ is correct. Transparent didn't work, nor did your other suggestion. :(

Answer (score 0):

Found two articles that may be of use to you.

[mobile-safari-background-image-scaling-quirk](http://www.teknocat.org/blog/web-development/show/6/mobile-safari-background-image-scaling-quirk)

and the other has to do with duplicate css.

[Background-image-doesn-t-show-up-in-Safari](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?302958-Background-image-doesn-t-show-up-in-Safari!)

at first it may not seem like you are doing this; but maybe changing your bgimage is causing the same problem.